# JavaScript object default method

Tags: javascript, oop, javascript-objects

I have a small question about methods on objects in javascript. I'm building a very small npm module, so I have a `module.exports = {}` statement.

Inside of it I have a `parsing` property with methods in it:

```
module.exports = {
    parsing: {
        parsing_method_1 : {
            fromFile: function(file){...},
            normal: function(string){...}
        },
     }
}
```

However, I would like to be able to call my method as `obj.parsing.parsing_method_1()` instead of `obj.parsing.parsing_method_1.normal()`... Like a reference to it's `normal` method

Is there a way to do so?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry for my confusion but will this not isolate other functions like fromFile?

Comment: No way unless you modify the object as the below answer

Comment: simply add variable like  `parsing.parsing_method_1=parsing.parsing_method_1.normal()`

Answer (score 0):

Efficiently construct `parsing_method_1` outside of the function. One way to do this is to create the object with two functions as properties, and assign the properties of the object to the `normal` function property.

```
var parsing_method_1_properties = {
  fromFile: function(file){...},
  normal: function(string){...}
};

// Assign properties of object to inner function.
Object.assign(parsing_method_1_properties.normal, parsing_method_1_properties);
```

Finally:

```
module.exports = {
  parsing: {
    parsing_method_1 : parsing_method_1_properties.normal,
  }
}
```

Now you can do `obj.parsing.parsing_method_1()`, `obj.parsing.parsing_method_1.fromFile()`, or infinitely recurse with `obj.parsing.parsing_method_1.normal.normal.normal.normal()`.

This is called a circular reference, where an object's property chain can eventually resolve to the object itself.